# Seeking an explanation for a tikzpicture code

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have found the following solution in stackexchange. It has been perfectly answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127401/23594) by @Jake.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    set layers=standard,
    domain=0:10,
    samples y=1,
    view={40}{20},
    hide axis,
    unit vector ratio*=1 2 1,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty,
    clip=false
]
\def\sumcurve{0}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.5,1.5,...,5.5}{
    \draw [on layer=background, gray!20] (axis cs:0,#1,0) -- (axis cs:10,#1,0);
    \addplot3 [on layer=main, blue!30, smooth, samples=101] (x,#1,{sin(#1*x*157))/(#1*2)});

    \addplot3 [on layer=axis foreground, very thick, blue,ycomb, samples=2] (10.5,#1,{1/(#1*2)});
    \xdef\sumcurve{\sumcurve + sin(#1*x*(157))/(#1*2)}
}
\addplot3 [red, samples=200] (x,0,{\sumcurve});

\draw [on layer=axis foreground]  (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:10,0,0);
\draw (axis cs:10.5,0.25,0) -- (axis cs:10.5,5.5,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I really liked the solution. I would be thankful if someone could explain the following features that have been utilized in the code so that I learn it and use it in the future.

- `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`: I read the manual and I still do not see its difference with `\foreach`. Why we are not using `foreach`?
- `\addplot3 (x,#1,{sin(#1*x*(157))/(#1*2)});`: what is the difference between `x` and `#1` in this line code? What values `x` will take?
- `\def\sumcurve{0}`: Does this one defines `y=0` curve?
- I am a little bit confused about the layers in the code. Why do we need the layers?
- `unit vector ratio*=1 2 1`: Is this used to simulate a nice three dimensional graph as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127401/23594)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` is different from `\foreach`.  To begin with `\foreach` introduces scoping, `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` does not.  Compare:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\def\myvalueA{0}
\def\myvalueB{0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=east] at (0,0) {foreach:};
  \foreach \myn in {1,2,3,4,5}
  { 
    \edef\myvalueA{\number\numexpr\myvalueA+\myn} 
    \node at (\myn,0) {\myvalueA};
  }
  \node at (6,0) {\myvalueA};

 \node[anchor=east] at (0,2) {pgfplotsinvokeforeach:};
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,5}
  {
    \edef\myvalueB{\number\numexpr\myvalueB+#1\relax}
    \node at (#1,2) {\myvalueB};
  }
  \node at (6,2) {\myvalueB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Because of the *scoping* introduced by `\foreach`, the new value of `\myvalueA` is lost after each iteration.  When the `\foreach` loop is completed, `\myvalueA` resumes the value it was initialized to.  In order to get around this with a `\foreach` loop, you would have to use `\xdef` instead of `\edef`.

`\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` does not introduce such scoping. So,  the new value of `\myvalueB` is *remembered* between interations.

With `\addplot3 (x,#1,{sin(#1*x*(157))/(#1*2)});`, `x` ranges over the domain defined within the `axis` declaration, `#1` ranges over the values passed to `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` in its first argument.

`\def\sumcurve{0}` merely initializes the `\sumcurve` to that in the first iteration

```
 \xdef\sumcurve{\sumcurve + sin(#1*x*(157))/(#1*2)}
```

the `\sumcurve` in the definition has a value to be added to.  Otherwise in the first iteration, `\sumcurve` would be an undefined control sequence.

If you compile without `layers` then the axes will appear visually on top of the graphs: that's most likely not what you want, particularly to maintain the visual effect of 3-d.

`unit vector ratio*=1 2 1` merely creates a nice scale for the axes.

Comment: @A2009, each curve on the graph could be labeled `y=f_i(x)`, initialize at `y=f_0(x)` where `f_0(x)=0`.  Then `\sumcurve` is essentially `y=f_0(x)+f_1(x)+f_2(x)+...+f_k(x)`.  If you initialize `\sumcurve` to `1`, that's essentially the same thing as setting `f_0(x)=1`.

Comment: Could you also please elaborate on the three layers that have been used, namely, `standard`, `main`, and `axis foreground`?

Comment: @A2009 They are merely `standard` names for configuring layers.  If you look at the documentation in `pgfplots` it explains under `/pgfplots/layers/standard` how these layers are applied.