# How can I create a chart with three dimensions?

Tags: graphics, charts

How can I create a chart like the one below (taken from http://blog.summify.com/2011/09/21/code-reviews-a-framework-for-startups/) in LaTeX:

[image]

Comment: The idea is similar to [Replicate the Fourier transform time-frequency domains correspondence illustration using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127375) you might find some helpful hints there.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the PGFPlots package. Example: http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/2d-functions-in-3d/

Comment: Can you extend your answer? Though unlikely, it is possible that pgfplots.net goes offline, the solution would be lost then. Looking closer at the example, we get redirected to TeX.SX -> [Plotting several 2d functions in a 3d graph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53794)