# Trying to get to grips with tikzpicture, where does r come from in the flowing script?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get to grips with tikzpicture and am looking at the Fourier expansion example (see [Replicate the Fourier transform time-frequency domains correspondence illustration using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/replicate-the-fourier-transform-time-frequency-domains-correspondence-illustrati) )

In Shuhao Cao's answer there is this piece of script:

```
\foreach \y in {0.5,1.5,...,5.5}{
\draw [cyan!50, domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,smooth] 
plot (\y,\x, {sin(4*\y*\x r)/\y });
```

But I can't see where 'r' is defied in '{sin(4*\y*\x r)/\y }'? is this an intrinsic function? I've ran Shuhao Cao's script and it works fine, but I don't understand what r is. Perhaps it simply stands for the units "radian"?

Comment: You nailed it, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Page 923 of the manual covers various aspects of PGF's parsing of mathematical expressions. These include:

> Various functions are recognized, so it is possible to parse `sin(.5*pi r)*60`, which means “the sine of 0.5 times π radians, multiplied by 60”. The argument of functions can be any expression.